# Cannot use the function hideCallout from react native maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am currently trying to close my callout when I press the X button of a card on my app.

My code is this. ** function of closing card **

```
  unsetCard = id => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      showCard: false,
    });

    this.markers.hideCallout();

    if (this.state.keyboard) {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }
  };
```

And this is my ** Map View code, I use RN Clustering **

```
<MapView
            // 
            mapRef={ref => (this.myMapRef = ref)}
            //
            onPress={this.unsetCard}>
            {this.props.data.map(marker => (
              <Marker
                key={marker.id}
                ref={ref => (this.markers = ref)}
               //
               }>
                <Callout
                  //
                  }}>
                  <CustomCallout title={marker.t} />
                </Callout>
              </Marker>
            ))}
          </MapView>
```

Finally the function of unset card is called in this component in the same file:

```
            <CustomCardWithImage
              close={() => this.unsetCard(this.state.cardInfo.id)}
            />
```

I would appreciate if someone told me how to use the ref to the marker, because as much as I try it does not work.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After seriously considering not continuing with this app, I took a break and solved the problem. Here is how you can use show or hide callout if you are interested:

**Initialize markers**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.markers = [];
  }
```

**Create markers refs**

```
<Marker
  key={marker.id}
  ref={ref => {
  this.markers[marker.id] = ref;
}}>
```

**Call where needed**

```
this.markers[id].hideCallout();
```

I hope someone finds it helpful someday